# How to monitor calls to stat?

Tags: stat, linux-audit, amazon-linux

I'd like to monitor calls to `stat` on any file within a directory. I know `inotifywait` can listen for file creation etc. but I don't know anything that can listen for `stat`. This is on Amazon Linux 2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

auditd can do that.

`man auditd.rules` -> System Call

Example: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/36278

Also consider its alternatives: https://github.com/slackhq/go-audit https://osquery.io/

Comment: I can't figure out how to restrict this to a specific directory. Closest I got is `auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S stat -F dir=/tmp/ooo -k mytest` but that doesn't show any logs. I also tried `-w /tmp/ooo` but that doesn't list `stat` calls.

Comment: You could offer a bounty for the question. I'm not well versed in the topic and it's far behind, so unlikely to be answered.